# Calculate EPSG:4326 coorditates from x,y pixels inside a tile

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

I have a 256x256 tile from OpenStreetMap tile server. Lets say `5/11/18.png`

And I have a X,Y pixel from this reference tile (not global) where `0 < x < 256` and `0 < y < 256`.

Is there any way to find the EPSG:4326 coordinates from this pixel?

Already try [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/calculate-lat-lon-bounds-for-individual-tile-generated-from-gdal2tiles) but can't get the explanation.

Actually every time I ask "Convert x,y" to google I get "x,y" as being the entire tile coordinate from the grid not the pixel from the tile.

EDIT: Just to illustrate here is the image at `5/11/18.png`. It is all I have. I have no way to know anything about the resolution or grids...

[image]

Comment: once you know the top left corner it is simple maths of dpi*scale*number of pixels, though the answer is likely to be in EPSG:3857 rather than EPSG:4326

Comment: Huh... almost got it. So... need I to know the DPI ? How can I guarantee this? I need to calculate this from many different sources not only OSM.

Comment: Should be defined in the tile matrix definition

Comment: Sorry.. you're making assumptions. What matrix definitions? I have only a URL to a tile that's not mine.

Comment: Then assume 96 DPI and hope for the best

Comment: You'll find all the necessary info here https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames and here https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

Comment: @Ian Turton sorry I'm not a Geographer. I'm a programmer. Hope is not an option here.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks. I think I may take the "Tile bounding box" part here ( https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Java ) then divide border difference by 256 to take each pixel and then sum pixel position... I'll start from here and post results.

Comment: if you don't know the scale or resolution then there is nothing to do - you just have a picture not data

Comment: @Ian Turton according to links pointed by TomazicM
 if I have an image 256x256 and I know the borders coordinates then I can know the coordinate of a given pixel: ( ( lonWest - lonEast ) / 256  ) * x. You may say "this is resolution" but I need to calculate by myself it was not given.